# How to return an array in without storing globally?

Tags: c

I have utitlity function which gives me a char buffer of individual bytes, when I provide it with a structure.

```
unsigned char complete[16] = { 0 };

char* construct_complete_array(socketType* m)
{
  unsigned char *temp = (unsigned char*) m;
  size_t j;

  for (j = 0; j < sizeof(*m); j++)
  {
    complete[j] = *(temp);
    printf("%.2x ", *(temp));
    *temp++;
  }

  return complete;
}

int diff_bit_calc(socketType* datanode, socketType* knode)
{
  char* result = construct_complete_array(datanode);
  size_t j;

  printf("\nPrinting result: \n");

  for (j = 0; j < sizeof(*datanode); j++)
  {
    printf("%.2x ", *(result));
    *result++;
  }
}
```

I want it to be a generic function which when provided with a structure will return me a char buffer of the structure. 
        I might have another invocation like

```
char* result1 = construct_complete_array(knode);
```

(I don't think having `complete[16] buffer` as global a good idea. Having it local and returning it is still a worser idea. )

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can't do that without dynamically allocating memory. Most people get around it by declaring the buffer in the calling function and passing that buffer to a function, which will then fill in the passed buffer.

In your specific case, I'm not so sure a function is necessary; it's rather short to do it inline, e.g.:

```
/* to get the bytes representing `something' into a char array */
char something_chars[sizeof(something)];
memcpy(something_chars, &something, sizeof(something));
```

Answer (score 1):

As for as I know, there are two ways to do that. 
Since the return value of the function is a pointer, so you must make sure that the memory you store result won't be destroyed. Other than using global variable, you can use dynamic allocating memory(like icktoofay said) or static keyword
(like Tay Wee Wen said).

- When using dynamic allocating memory, the user of this function should remember to **free() outside the function**.
- When using static keyword inside the block, there is a problem of **overriding**. If you call the function several times, only the last return value was kept.

By the way, `*temp++;` is a little strange, why not use `temp++;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array static inside the function.

```
char* construct_complete_array(socketType* m){

    static unsigned char complete[16]= {0};
    unsigned char *temp = (unsigned char*)m;
    size_t j;
    for (j = 0;j<sizeof(*m);j++){
        complete[j] = *(temp);
        printf("%.2x ", *(temp));
        *temp++;
    }
    return complete;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to change your interface a bit:

```
char* construct_complete_array(socketType* m, char temp[]);
```

then on the calling side you can use a compound literal to provide `temp`

```
char* result = construct_complete_array(datanode, (char[sizeof *datanode]){ 0 });
```

If you have to repeat that in several places you could put that into a macro

```
#define CONSTRUCT_ARRAY(X) construct_complete_array((X), (char[sizeof *(X)]){ 0 })
```

so then again your call side looks almost as you had it before

```
char* result = CONSTRUCT_ARRAY(datanode);
```

For this to work you just have to have in mind that the value in `result` points to local data with the same life time as `result` itself.